# how to transfer data from one mysql database to another and mapping the data with different column names using python

Tags: python, mysql

How can I transfer data from one MySQL database to another?  The other database may have different field names, except id, which will act as the primary key.

I have tried using mysqlalchemy, but the only data that gets mapped are the filed names that are same in both databases.

```
import sqlalchemy


db1 = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mysql+pymysql://root:@localhost:3306/mydatabase1")
db2 = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mysql+pymysql://root:@localhost:3306/nava")

print('Writing...')


query = ''' (SELECT * FROM customers1)'''
df = pd.read_sql(query, db1)
print(df)
#query1 = ''UPDATE 'leap' SET   `leap`value '''

df.to_sql('nap', db2, index=False, if_exists='append')
```

i get error that other database dosent have same field names but what i want is that even if the field names change data still gets mapped with reference to the primary key id

Comment: import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy

Comment: Why not to change column names in `df` according to your target tables column names?

Answer (score 0):

this is the program that i asked about in the above question but there was an error so code hasent appeared in the right way

import pandas as pd

import sqlalchemy

db1 = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mysql+pymysql://root:@localhost:3306/mydatabase1")

db2 = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mysql+pymysql://root:@localhost:3306/nava")

print('Writing...')

query = ''' (SELECT * FROM customers1)'''

df = pd.read_sql(query, db1)

df.to_sql('nap', db2, index=False, if_exists='append')

Comment: please help i really need the sollution as early as possible